# C++ Excel Automation Copy Parameter

Tags: c++, excel

I'm trying to copy a range of Excel cells between two different sheets using Excel automation via C++. I am using excel8.cpp to interface with Excel.

I want to call the [Range.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) method but I'm not sure how exactly to pass the destination parameter. I think this is the correct way:

```
    //ranges already defined
    //XL::Range range1, range2;

    COleVariant myVar;
    VariantInit(myVar);
    myVar.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
    myVar.pdispVal = (LPDISPATCH)range2;
    range1.Copy(myVar);
```

However when I try this, I get the message "Copy method of Range class failed".

Also, I don't want to pass an optional Variant into the copy function because there is a bug I have come across with the clipboard causing Copy and Paste to fail randomly.

Comment: wouldn't it be `range1.Copy(myVar);`? You say you've defined `range1` and `range2`, but what's `range`? and how is `range2` assigned?

Comment: also, ...my deepest sympathies for doing this in C++... is C# or .NET (heck, or VBA) not an option?

Comment: Whoops. Range is supposed to be range1. I will update the question.

C++ is how we have always done automation. Is there a better way to run a vba script from a c++ application?

Comment: Range2 is initialized using Worksheet.GetRange()

`//already existing XL::_Worksheet in_Worksheet`<br/>
`in_Worksheet.GetRange(COleVariant(CString(str_ColRow)), covOptional);`

Comment: I don't understand your question - you're not running any VBA here, you're working against the COM stuff behind Excel. The Excel object model is COM, not VBA. This has nothing to do whatsoever with VBA. As for a "better way" ....well, it depends on what you're trying to do here, and more importantly *why* you're doing it. A C++ application that needs to manipulate an Excel worksheet, let alone copy its content to the clipboard, strikes me as something rather... unusual.

Comment: You're right, there's no actual VBA involved. The only reason I link to a VBA documentation is the COM documentation is non-existant but the functions are pretty similar to the VBA functions.

I'm not sure why you find anything I'm doing unusual. I need to create an excel report based on existing data in the software. We need to copy ranges between different workbooks. What's so unusual about that?

Comment: Well, people generally automate Excel with VBA, not C++. Doing that in VBA avoids many pitfalls you're getting to put up with in C++. I'd probably just generate a .csv file and use Excel to import it, and then pivot it perhaps. Or use VBA to lay it out as needed. But straight-up Excel automation in C++.... you're a brave warrior man!